# Android GreenDAO Generator Error Gradle 2.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, greendao

I have updated my Android Studio. Now when I run my DAOGenerator I receive this error:

```
Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'xxxxxx'.

    Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
    Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0.
    Required by:
    :curiocity-app:unspecified
    > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0 available for offline mode.
```

I have activated the offline mode.

This is my graddle from generator module

apply plugin: 'java'

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao-generator:2.2.0'
}
```

This is my application graddle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXXXXXXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", include: 'native-libs.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:2.2.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao-generator:2.2.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'in.workarounds.typography:typography:0.0.8'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.2'
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;

    }
    compile project(':sdktools')
    compile project(':debugkit')

    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-manipulation:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core-slh:3.1.0@aar'
    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')


}
```

Regards

Comment: can you show your build.gradle?

Comment: Thanks Alvaro. I have updated my question

Comment: Please leave offline mode, because the new version has to be fetched online.

Comment: Thanks greenrobot, but in my gradle preferences in AS the offline work option is unchecked.

Comment: Have you updated to Android Studio 2.0 yet?

Comment: Yes I am using 2.0